# What does this C# code do & convert to PHP?

Tags: c#, php, pdf

I want to convert this code into PHP, it's a function that hides layers on a PDF file, but I don't understand how it is doing it.

```
        public static void HidePDFLayers(string pdf_file, string output_file)
    {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdf_file);
        PdfStamper stamp = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(output_file, FileMode.Create));

        pdf_num_pages = reader.NumberOfPages;
        Dictionary<string, PdfLayer> layers = stamp.GetPdfLayers();

        int count = 0;

        foreach(KeyValuePair<string, PdfLayer> entry in layers )
        {
            PdfLayer layer = (PdfLayer)entry.Value;
            layer.On = false;
            count++;
        }

        stamp.Close();

        Console.WriteLine("[*] Number Of Layers Hidden: " + count);
        PDFToImages(output_file);
    }
```

Does this create a new PDF with all the layers hidden (which layers, surely if they were all hidden then there would be nothing on the PDF?)

How would I do the same with PHP?

Comment: Do you have `PdfReader` in a PHP version to use?

Comment: That looks like iTextSharp to me. Is there even a PHP port of that? Will you be writing the PDF manipulation code yourself?

Comment: Thanks for the -2 guys, this is a genuine question that I seriously need help with, I'm sorry that I don't read C# so well, but that is afterall why I have to ask the question.

Comment: I can write straight PHP very well, if I know what this above code actually does. Which still remains my question. Thanks.

Comment: This code is using a PDF library that provides the functionality you need. All of the logic is contained in the PdfReader and PdfStamper objects. You won't be able to convert this to PHP unless you find an equivalent PDF library in PHP.

Comment: Enough with the minuses. I know you think this is a bad question, but it doesn't excuse the fact that I have asked it and would very much appreciate to know what this is doing in plain words. You don't have to port it to PHP for me, I can do that, please just explain what it is doing.

Comment: Thank you Brandon, so what about that for loop? Is it hiding all the layers, or just some of them?

Comment: @Alasdair - The code is doing exactly as the method name implies. Overall I would say the code is pretty solid. I would add a try-finally to make sure the stamper object is closed though.

Comment: Is it hiding all layers, or just some?

Comment: I just noticed the global assignment of `pdf_num_pages`. I just lost a bit of respect for whoever wrote this.

Comment: It opens the pdf for reading and passes the handle to PdfStamper(whatever that does, I think as its coded it grabs only the first layer), counts how many layers are in the document, loops through each layer and sets to false while incrementing a counter, then uses the first layer to create an image... I could be wrong tho ;s

Comment: Hey check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/560583/which-is-the-best-pdf-library-for-php

Comment: OK, thank you Lawrence & V4Vendetta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see here http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfStamper.html the documentation says, it gets the layers in a PDF document. So I think it gets all the layers in a PDF document.

Then it loops through all the layers, setting their visibility to false, which hides them.

PS. The more you say about the minuses, the more you are going to get I guess ;)

Comment: Thanks. I don't care about getting minuses myself, it's just the principle that the people here are so elitist that they give someone a negative for asking a beginner's question. We all have to start somewhere.

Comment: @Alasdair - You have to understand how poor a question you have asked here. What isn't you don't get about he code? Is it the syntax or the library they are using? Also consider that this answer does not explain how to convert that code to PHP. As for being elitist, well you are probably right about that.

Comment: The question is poor, I agree, but that's because I have never written C# code in my life. I have this code, which doesn't work, and have to rewrite it, and all I can do is rewrite it in PHP, because that is what I know. Luckily I can understand most of what the C# is doing since it's not so far from PHP, but this function I couldn't understand. Everyone here obviously thought I'm a very bad C# developer, but I'm not a C# developer at all, only a PHP developer in a sticky situation with some code I don't understand that have to fix because the person who wrote it didn't finish it off properly.

Comment: I'm sorry if I have been rude, I have had a bad day trying to get to the bottom of this and posting it on StackOverFlow was my last straw. Now I know that it uses iTextSharp and it disables all layers. Now my plan is to strip all this code down that can't be ported into functions I can compile as standalone executables and execute from PHP. Do you know how to compile a C# project with Mono?